# How to convert special characters into literal characters in jQuery Mask plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I have a form that uses [jQuery mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). In most field inputs, it uses masks as "99999-999" and works: The plugin displays the "-" char in the field automatically. The user doesn't need to enter the "-" character.
However, when I specify "999,00" it changes the "0" character to accept every number, and that's not what this specific input requires. Is there a way to change it to the literal "0" char, instead of the 0 that means [0-9]?

PS: I already tried to use mask translation. Instead of displaying the '0' char automatically, it only disallows the input of every char but "0".

```js
$("#foobar").mask("999,00", {translation : 
  {'0' : {pattern: /0/}}
});
```

Comment: are you trying to avoid having number 0 entered into the masked field ?

Comment: @DinoMyte No, I need it only to automatically enter "00" after the first 3 numbers are entered. And it needs to be by masking.

Comment: You can use "0" literally by removing it from Mask's global translations (and/or "renaming" it if you still want to use _something_ that produces the same behavior). I did that, without editing Mask's code, here: http://jsfiddle.net/en7o31t4/1/. However, I still had issues. 1) It only adds the ",00" after you type any key after _already_ entering the 3 first digits; not sure how to make them appear _automatically_ after 999. 2) Any subsequent edits can get kind of funky; the literal zeros still seems to interact buggily with the regexs for the other numbers. Wanted to send you it anyway, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#data").mask("99,ZZ", {
    translation: {
        'Z': {
          pattern: /[0]/, 
          fallback: '0'
        }
      }
  });
```

you can check the result [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPwoEj).

Comment: It actually didn't work for my project, but I tested in others sites and it worked. I'll try to solve this compatibility issue. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: *Update:* My project had a non-updated version of the mask-plugin. Therefore, the "fallback" property wasn't being recognized.